# enter text with single quote in database using wpdb

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Following code truncates every string that has a single quote in it. I tried with and without stripslashes, tried stripslashes_deep but none of them works. If for example name is "Mac Donald's" its saved as "Mac Donald" and simply cut off where the single quote is.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)  
{
    $$key = stripslashes($value);
    echo $key."--".$$key."<br>";

}

$wpdb->update("x_data",array('name'=>$d_name,'address'=>$address,'city'=>$city,'state'=>$state,'postalcode'=>$postalcode,'phone'=>$phone,'fax'=>$fax,'email'=>$email),array('uid' => $user_ID,'id'=>$gid));
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Should work, according to [$wpdb docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows).

Comment: Have you tried [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)?

Comment: @JustinWood - WP class escapes / prepares the values on it's own.

Comment: i know it should work.. but it istn working.. :) and i am going crazy about this..

Comment: any character works except '

Comment: @cale_b I thought it should. just found it weird that this was happening period.

Comment: This is still a problem as of WordPress 3.9.2.  The internal prepare() that $wpdb->update() does should protect against this, but doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try str_replace like this:

```
$value = str_replace("'", "", $value);
```